Trouble importing Json into Azure Log Analytics
I'm trying to ingest some Microsoft Flow API data into Azure Log Analytics.
Goal is that a Power Automate send a JSON with the Flows details to Log Analytics.
Here is the sample JSON :
{
    "body": [
        {
            "NAME": "XXXXX",
            "ID": "/providers/Microsoft.ProcessSimple/environments/XXXXXXX/flows/XXXXXXX/runs/XXXXX",
            "TYPE": "Microsoft.ProcessSimple/environments/flows/runs",
            "START": "2024-04-23T21:59:59.8317555Z",
            "END": "2024-04-23T22:23:08.8817048Z",
            "STATUS": "Succeeded"
        },
        {
            "NAME": "XXXXX",
            "ID": "/providers/Microsoft.ProcessSimple/environments/XXXXXXX/flows/XXXXXXX/runs/XXXXX",
            "TYPE": "Microsoft.ProcessSimple/environments/flows/runs",
            "START": "2024-04-22T21:59:59.6368987Z",
            "END": "2024-04-22T22:25:59.2561963Z",
            "STATUS": "Succeeded"
        },
        {
            "NAME": "XXXXX",
            "ID": "/providers/Microsoft.ProcessSimple/environments/XXXXXXX/flows/XXXXXXX/runs/XXXXX",
            "TYPE": "Microsoft.ProcessSimple/environments/flows/runs",
            "START": "2024-04-21T22:00:00.4246672Z",
            "END": "2024-04-21T22:24:54.7721214Z",
            "STATUS": "Succeeded"
        },
        {
            "NAME": "XXXXX",
            "ID": "/providers/Microsoft.ProcessSimple/environments/XXXXXXX/flows/XXXXXXX/runs/XXXXXX",
            "TYPE": "Microsoft.ProcessSimple/environments/flows/runs",
            "START": "2024-04-17T09:49:45.8327243Z",
            "END": "2024-04-17T09:50:46.3459275Z",
            "STATUS": "Succeeded"
        }
    ]
}

First time using KQL, i asked GPT a lot but nothing really work
My last attempt was to go with mv-apply instead of mv-expand :
source
| extend parsedJson = parse_json(body)
| mv-apply parsedItem = parsedJson on 
(
    project 
        TimeGenerated = todatetime(parsedItem['START']), // Convert 'START' to DateTime
        Name = tostring(parsedItem['NAME']),
        ID = tostring(parsedItem['ID']),
        Type = tostring(parsedItem['TYPE']),
        StartTime = tostring(parsedItem['START']),
        EndTime = tostring(parsedItem['END']),
        Status = tostring(parsedItem['STATUS'])
)

Still no luck, throwing me some mismatch error :
Error occurred while compiling query in query: SyntaxError:0x00000003 at 3:11 : mismatched input 'parsedItem' expecting {<EOF>, ';', '|', '.', '*', '[', '=~', '!~', 'notcontains', 'containscs', 'notcontainscs', '!contains', 'contains_cs', '!contains_cs', 'nothas', 'hascs', 'nothascs', '!has', 'has_cs', '!has_cs', 'startswith', '!startswith', 'startswith_cs', '!startswith_cs', 'endswith', '!endswith', 'endswith_cs', '!endswith_cs', 'matches regex', '/', '%', '+', '-', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '==', '<>', '!=', 'and', 'between', 'contains', 'has', 'in', '!between', '!in', 'or'}


it seems that inside 'Body' element, each segment is a number, and i believe this is why it's hurting me so much !

can you provide expected output

Hi, Well if i could have a column in my log Analytics Table for each of the properties in the JSON sample above, that would be great
NAME|ID|TYPE|START|END|STATUS

You have the json data stored in a column in  a table in Log analytics?

No, data is in the JSON format above in Power Automate.
When i try to create a custom log analytics table with that JSON is where i have the problem.

You can use below design in Logic Apps to send data and create a table with custom json:
Taken your input in compose:

Then:

Parse_json:
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "body": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "NAME": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "ID": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "TYPE": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "START": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "END": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "STATUS": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "NAME",
                    "ID",
                    "TYPE",
                    "START",
                    "END",
                    "STATUS"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

Connection of Azure Log Analytics Data Collector:

Taken values from below:

Output:

Table got created:

Logic App:


Hi, it seems that your way to go is working nicely ! Thank you very much
Adding to this solution : Do not try to create the table in log analytics before.
When using the "Send Data" in Power Automate, put a table name that does not exist ant it wil create it into Log Analytics.

I guess that you try to write this a ingestion-time transformation. The query language in this case is limited and doesn't support full KQL as it has to be executed in very large scale with no delay on the data. Specifically, mv-apply isn't supported. See supported KQL here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/data-collection-transformations-structure
Meir

Hi, Yup i was not aware of that specific limitation ! I guess that's why i could not get it to Work ! MFSFT should be a bit clearer about the mv-apply lack of support in their error message !
Thank you
